# VS2010 MVC and Entity Framework Model in Separate Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I'm experimenting with ASP.NET MVC in VS2010. I'm trying to use an Entity Framework model in a referenced project within the main MVC project. However, although I can manually create a view that can work with the EF Model in the other project, I can't use the in-built scaffolding features.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

For reference, I've made sure that my web.config  element includes a reference to the namespace of the referenced project that contains the EF model.

Thanks,

Richard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to either wait for VS2010 Beta 2 (as the MVC project type is not yet supported properly in Beta 1) or use the ASP.Net MVC 1.1 beta that adds support for VS 2010 Beta 1 at: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=28527

see: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/18/aspnetmvc-vs2010-beta1.aspx & http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/09/aspnetmvc-vs10beta1-roadmap.aspx

If you are already using the Codeplex Beta, just ensure that you have built the referenced assembly before attempting to auto generate your Views and that you have an assembly/project reference to your Models assembly/project.